# no module name typedefs when use pyinstaller

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import, pyinstaller

Recently, I used sklearn to do linear regression analysis, and the code was compiled and run by me. But when I packaged to the .exe file with pyinstaller, An error has occurred："ImportError:no module name typedefs" after running. When I added "--hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" after the command, my program stopped running directly. This question is bothering me now. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, and adding

```
--hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

to my pyinstaller command-line call fixed my problem. Therefore I suspect that an additional problem occurred in your case

Answer (score 0):

No no no, you have to run pyinstaller again like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_program.py --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

I think you added that line to the **already compiled program**, hence your error.